# Writing a function as a sum of its odd and even parts

Tags: functions

I have the following question and the solution along with it but I can't get my head around what's been done.

The aim is to write the following function as a sum of even and odd functions:

$h(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
e^x, & \text{if $ x\geq 0$}
\end{cases}
$

I am aware that any function $f(x)$ can be written as:

$f(x) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(h(x)+h(-x))}_{f_{even}(x)}+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(h(x)-h(-x))}_{f_{odd}(x)}$

I attempted to do it myself but it was incorrect.

The correct method was to find the following:

We have

$h(-x) = 
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
e^{-x}, & \text{if $ x\leq 0$}
\end{cases}
$

Hence:

$h_{even}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-x}),  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}(1+e^{x}), & \text{if $ x> 0$} \\
\ 1,  & \text{ if $x=0$}\end{cases}
$

$h_{odd}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-x}),  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}(e^{x}-1), & \text{if $ x> 0$} \\
\ 0,  & \text{ if $x=0$}\end{cases}
$

My problem is I have no idea how these functions were found.. I'm sure it's as simple as applying the formula I stated above but I think perhaps because they are piece wise functions I am not entirely sure how this happened.

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Further Info:

I think I understand the formula but applying it to examples particularly is where I struggle, as in the actual calculation is what I don't understand.

For example, to calculate $h_{even}(x)$ we should do the addition of the following functions, if I am correct:

$
\frac{1}{2}h(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $x<0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}e^x, & \text{if $ x\geq 0$}
\end{cases} $

$\frac{1}{2}h(-x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}, & \text{if $ x\leq 0$}
\end{cases}$

But my issue is, how do you combine these? How can you deduce that for example $h_{even}(x)=1$, if $x=0$ purely from this addition.

I guess my question is quite simple really as in just how to add piece wise functions when the conditions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your expression 
$$f(x) = \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(h(x)+h(-x))}_{f_{even}(x)}+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(h(x)-h(-x))}_{f_{odd}(x)}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}h(x) + \frac{1}{2}h(x) + \frac{1}{2}h(-x)-\frac{1}{2}h(-x)$$
$$f(x) = h(x)$$
This derivation should help you out, as finding $f_{even}$ and $f_{odd}$ is now just a matter of calculation.

Comment: I think perhaps it is the calculation I am struggling with.. I have added more information at the end of the question.

Comment: As for your question on how to add piecewise functions. You can split up the bounds further so that you have $x>0$, $x<0$, and $x=0$. Then you can go about adding up the similar parts of the functions. Does that help?

Comment: Yes !! God it's so simple now, thank you so much ! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac12 \Big(2f(x)\Big)=\frac12 \Big(f(x)+f(x)\Big)=\frac12 \Big(f(x)-f(-x)+f(x)+f(-x)\Big)=\underbrace{\frac12 (f(x)+f(-x))}_{\text{Even function}}+\underbrace{\frac12 (f(x)-f(-x))}_{\text{Odd function}}$$

In your solution $h(x)=f(x)$